# Indeterministic dll check in with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, tfs

All external libraries I use in my solutions are in the Lib folder of respective projects within a solution and all have their `Build Action` property set to 'Content' and `Copy to Output Directory` property set to 'Copy if newer'.

When I check in my solution into TFS, some dll files are copied to TFS and checked in with a blue lock appearing next to them, and some are not, prompting my team members to ask me for copies of these dll files in order to be able to build the solution...

If File Properties of all these dll files are the same and these are all .NET assemblies, what is it that determines if a dll will be checked in or not, and just what is the most appropriate `Build Action` for a dll library?

Comment: Build action should control whether the DLLs are copied to the output (bin) directory.  It should not control anything about source code control on your source directory.  You'll need to pend the add/edit changes if the DLLs are changing.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, If Build Action Property controls whether the dlls are copied to the output directory, what is the purpose of Copy to Output Directory Property?

Comment: Oop, sorry, I meant the Copy to Output Directory property.  In any case, I meant to say that they don't have an impact on source control.

Comment: You're right, they don't and I think I figured it out, I think it is about how you add the DLL file to your project... I'll post what I found as an answer if no one else answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered is that it depends on how you add the dll files to your solution.

If the dll file is first copied to your Lib folder and added to your project from there (copy/paste into Lib folder in Solution Explorer), it is not checked in and copied to the TFS.

If the dll file is added to your project (copy/paste into Lib folder in Solution Explorer) from its original location VS will copy the file to your Lib folder and check it into TFS.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a project or a folder to your source control, dolls and executables are ignored by default. you need to go to the exclusion tab and select the dlls you want to check in explicitly. that's why you have the seemingly random behavior.